# Border rendering suddenly not supported by sequencer & odd problem with rendering

Tags: rendering, camera

Whenever I render a single frame of my animation, for all key frames except one it will just give me black real quick while that odd one out will show me an older render of mine from that same keyframe. I could switch cameras, change the position of anything in the scene, or alter rendering settings but it will just give me back the inital 720p render without even looking like it rendered anything at all.

When border is enabled in the rendering, I get an error message saying "Border rendering is not supported by sequencer."

Comment: If you expect help, please make an effort to describe the situation... nobody but you knows what kind of scene you are dealing with, or how you set up your sequencer or what kind of settings you are using... use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help users understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue, but then figured it out. By unchecking *Render Region* under *Dimensions*, it was solved.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

**1)** You have some sort of image or image sequence already in the sequencer that is causing the render to look bad, because rendering defaults to sequencer when some sort of file is in it.

**2)** Border rendering is not supported by the sequencer, so it will give you an error message when enabled. Thus proving something is in the sequencer.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have my video starting on 0 frame.  It was starting later. Moving video back to 0 Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off **border rendering** (**render region** blender 2.8) in **Rendering** -> **Properties** -> **Output properties**
fixed it for me.

[image]

I recall playing with menus and the hypothesis is that I checked it somewhere along the way to cause that problem in the first place.

Note: it is a solution with picture for `border rendering not supported` issue which I encountered and found this QA via google, as for particular issue raised by OP, I think deleting items is the sequencer might help as I understood another answer.

Answer (score 0):

try these settings:
from output settings:

1. file format: FFmpeg Video
2. encoding > container: Matroska
3. video > video codec: H.264 : High Quality : Good : 25
4. Audio > Audio Codec: MP3 : 192 : 1.000
5. Post Processing : ckeck Composing : check Sequesncer : Dither = 1.33

after this try rendering animation, it worked for me :)