# How to make video with image Sequence?

Tags: image, video-sequence-editor, video

When I do render animation with image Sequence , it doesn't work with the message 'Border rendering is not supported by image Sequencer' I think that's why I chose Resolution X:1500 Y:399 instead of 1080p?
but I need a this proportion for some reason. so I want to keep this Resolution's proportion and make video with those images. How can I do that?

Comment: these answer might be related to your issue..
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144754/border-rendering-suddenly-not-supported-by-sequencer-odd-problem-with-renderin

Comment: now I uncheck render region, but there is problem height not divisible by 2

Comment: can't 400 instead of 399 do it for you?
sorry if it's a dumb answer...I don't know much about resolutions.

Comment: I could solve this problem with your answers, Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your Render Resolution Y = 399. You didn't mention your render settings but I assume that your output format is: FFMPEG Video with an H.264 codec. The way this encoder works is by dividing your image into macroblocks of a fixed size (e.g. 4x4) and compress these blocks in parallel. Therefore your width and height must be divisible by 2.
If you should change your Height to 400, I think the problem will be fixed.

If you need this 1500 x 399 resolution, you can render it out as a PNG sequence. Then, you can use FFMPEG to create a movie (e.g. MP4) of it. There are plenty of solutions on the internet to do this; see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788967/ffmpeg-width-not-divisible-by-2-375x500-error.

You will find a more elaborate answer for this common question on https://vse-docs.readthedocs.io/extra-tools/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html

Comment: I could solve this problem with your answers, Thank you so much